# IE7 doesn't put sentence a child row, cutting sentence

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, overflow

There are a lot of varying length tag divs in tag wrapper div. There isn't any problem for IE8,9, FF,Chrome,Safari and opera but it broken for IE7. How can I fix this issue?

HTML:

```
<div class="tag-wrapper">
    <div class="tag"><a href="#">text text text</a></div>
    <div class="tag"><a href="#">text text</a></div>
    <div class="tag"><a href="#">text text</a></div>
    <div class="tag"><a href="#">text text text</a></div>
    <div class="tag"><a href="#">text text text text</a></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tag-wrapper{
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 12px 12px 12px 20px;
    width: 500px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid #000;
 }

.tag-wrapper .tag{
    background:url(img/corner02.png) no-repeat 0 0; 
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    display:inline-block;
    height:24px;
    margin: 0 10px 9px 0;
    float:left;    
}

.tag-wrapper .tag a:link{
    width:auto;
    overflow:visible;
    height:24px;
    line-height:24px;
    padding:0 5px 0 5px;
    background:#F00;
    float:left;
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;   
 }

.tag-wrapper .tag a:hover{
    color:#000;   
 }
```

Screenshot for IE8,IE9,Chrome,Firefox,Safari,Opera

[image]

Screenshot for IE7

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/B7Tjw/2/

Comment: Try to add `white-space:pre` to `.tag-wrapper .tag a:link` : http://jsfiddle.net/B7Tjw/3/ . You can use separated "ie7.css" and conditional comment to include it instead of combining it into "normal" CSS.

Answer (score 0):

try this code: it is working fine.

```
.tag-wrapper .tag a:link{
    width:auto;
    overflow:visible;
    height:24px;
    line-height:24px;
    padding:0 5px 0 5px;
    background:#F00;
    float:left;
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold; 
    white-space:pre;
}
```